Get text from XML in Kotlin
I want to make a function in Kotlin that will retrieve the text putted in by user
Here is xml:
android:id="@+id/Nick_Name"

android:layout_width="150dp"

android:layout_height="60dp"

android:text="ИМЯ ФАМИЛИЯ"

android:textFontWeight="1"

tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp"

tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="610dp"

tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>`

And I don't know how to get it with the Kotlin function.
Please, I will be happy for any help.
P.S. I am new to the language and dumb
I tried a ViewfindbyID but it didn't work cause I am dumb

Please, take some time to read how to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Assuming you want to retrieve text from TextView:
    fun getTextFromTextView() {
    val txtView: TextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.Nick_Name)
    val text: String = txtView?.text.toString()
}


Thank you , I just saw that I had missed a indentifier it was EditText, but I found my way around it, thanks for the help again
